# Does anyone know where I can find a free efficient frontier tool, or an informative and legitamate/academic graph of the efficient frontier?

Tags: stocks, bonds, asset-allocation, commodities, risk-management

I'd like to build a portfolio based upon modern portfolio theory and I'd like to find a tool I can use to calculate the proper mix of asset classes. Can anyone help with this? I think a good chart/graph showing stocks, bonds, oil, etc. along the efficient frontier would suffice as well.

Comment: Excel can do this with some formulas. It's worth noting that the efficient frontier is a historical picture of what optimal allocation *would have been*

Answer (score 1):

This could help you if you have access to Mathematica:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39409/363

This answers more on the lines of the 'academic' part of your question.  It's not a turn-key solution.  You'd have to work on it to turn it to your application.